# Google Analytics API segment vs. filter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My goal is to get `ga::users`, `ga::sessions` and `ga::avgSessionDuration` for all sessions that visited page path containing `/mockeroo` from Google Analytics API v4. Ignoring session duration for now, it is my understanding that a filter clause like `ga:page contains /mockeroo` and `sessions::condition::ga:page contains /mockeroo` should produce the same results for at least number of users and number of sessions. However, I cannot replicate the results on Google Analytics (which is using the segment constraint) with my API call (which is using the filter clause). Am I not understanding the difference between a filter clause and a segment correctly?

Comment: can you show screenshots/numbers of what you get?

Comment: please include your code and discribe any issues you are having with your solution